# Extend IPrincipal in .NET Core 2.1 with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-authentication

I'm trying to extend `IPrincipal` in .NET Core with Windows Authentication.

In a previous project (using .NET Framework 4.6.1) on `Application_Start()` I added the code below to extend `IPrincipal`:

```
protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Identity != null && e.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        NgUser opPrincipal = CustomStaticMethod.GetUserAD();
        HttpContext.Current.User = opPrincipal;
     }
 }
```

And this is my custom class

```
public class NgUser : IPrincipal
{
    // code removed for abbr ...
}
```

Then every time in a controller casting `HttpContext.Current.User` as `CustomPrincipal` I'd have access to the custom properties without having to use claims or using static extensions or storing an object in session.

Now in .NET Core I've seen you can [customize claims transformation](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) and I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214520/asp-net-extending-iprincipal/3214586#3214586) and they basically extended `IPrincipal`.

I'd prefer to extend `IPrincipal` with my custom class, register it in `Startup.cs` and be able to access it in my controllers.

Surely this is doable, question is how?

I hope this is clear and some one can help me.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very doable. The easiest way is to add a piece of middleware, which behaves similar to `OnAuthenticate`, to the `Configure()` pipeline in .NET Core. Here you'll swap out the IPrincipal. Note, this only works if the web app is set to run with Windows Authentication only in IIS/IIS Express. Anonymous authentication adds extra overhead.

If you have this simple Win auth setup, in your `Startup.cs` put this near the top of your `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method:

```
// Because IIS automatically captures the user login, by the time the app is touched
// in any request, the context (ctx) User is already present.
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
  if (ctx.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
  {
    NgUser opPrincipal = CustomStaticMethod.GetUserAD();
    ctx.User = opPrincipal;
  }

  // be sure to continue the rest of the pipeline!
  await next.Invoke();
});
```

```

Comment: Hi @Balah. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed :)